# do i need an app and a pages folder in next 13?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I am building a page which should only utilize the pages folder, but create next app made an app folder with a global css. I would think that it should be possible to only use the pages folder and apply global styles to it. I end up with two globals.css when using app and pages, because pages does not apply globals.css.

How to structure a project like that?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new next app (`npx create-next-app@latest`), it asks you whether you want to use the new app router or the old pages directory. Choose "No" there:

[image]

Comment: so what is the new way of doing it in next 13? using app is recommended over pages?

Comment: @n79qk272x57w46w9 By the Next.js team yes it recommended to completely use app dir. The community though is still using the pages for most of the projects.

Comment: good, then I should use the app folder, until the next breaking thing comes lol... move fast and destroy things.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need an app folder you can only work with page folder, in [Nextjs docs](https://nextjs.org/docs)  you can toggle between

[image]

That's great!

you can delete the app folder if the CSS is the only dependency you need for it and create your own.

**Update:** if you are in the application first steps better is to go with brc-dd answer and create a new project and does not use an app router

Comment: i think the app folder is the new way of doing it. why use pages.. this is only for people who have to transition from it. eventually they will remove pages.

Comment: @n79qk272x57w46w9 it was just to answer your question but I also recommend using the app router